# Using Tkinter enter datas into Database

Tags: python, database, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import pymysql
from tkinter import messagebox
connection=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='',database='loginform')
cursor=connection.cursor()
# cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE LOGIN1(Name varchar(20),Class varchar(20))")
root=Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
name=StringVar()
class1=StringVar()
def submit():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO LOGIN1(Name,Class,Dob,Address,Phone) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                   (name.get(),class1.get()))
    connection.commit()
    messagebox.showinfo("Login",'Login completed')
Label(root,text="NAME").grid(row=1,column=1)
E1=Entry(root,textvariable=name).grid(row=1,column=2)
Label(root,text="CLASS").grid(row=2,column=1)
E2=Entry(root,textvariable=class1).grid(row=2,column=2)
Button(root,text="SUBMIT",command='submit',bg='gray',fg='white').grid(row=7,column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Datas not saved into database while using Tkinter,Im not getting any error , Form with label name and class worked. Connected with database, but enterd data not saved

Comment: The INSERT statement has five placeholders, but only two values (name and class) are provided. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- `command='submit'` should be `command=submit` instead
- there are five placeholders (`%s`) in the INSERT statement, but only 2 values `(name.get(), class1.get())` are provided.  You need to create input widgets for the other three values (`Dob`, `Address` and `Phone`)